# AWE Enable for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

AWE is not enabled on our SQL Server 2005 which is 32-bit, but operating system is 64-bit.

Can/should we enable AWE bcos SQL/OS both on different bit type.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allocate more than 4GB of RAM to your SQL Server instance then yes, you should enable AWE.